# Electric field calculation gives opposite direction

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

We have a finite line of charge of length l positioned as shown from x to x+l [image]

I want to find the electric field at the point 0. I have calculated the electric potential to be the following: $$V=\frac{λ}{4\piε_0}\ln\frac{x+l}{x}$$ Then by definition $$\vec E=-\nabla V\\=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\hat x=-\frac{λ}{4\piε_0}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x}\right )\hat x=-\frac{λ}{4\piε_0}\left(\frac{x-x-l}{x(x+l)}\right)\hat x\\\vec E=\frac{λl}{4\piε_0x(x+l)}\hat x$$

However, it is obvious that E at 0 is towards the left, so I should get -x hat.

While calculating V I integrated from x to x+l, should it maybe be the other way around?

Where have I made the mistake?

Comment: Hey, I've edited my answer. The previous one was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You differentiated the potential after inserting the $y,z$ coordinates of the point where the field is measured. The correct way is the following (I've relabelled the x-coordinate of the position of the left end of the rod to $x_0$):

$$V(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}d^3\vec{r}$$

\begin{align}
V(x,y,z)&=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{x'=x_0}^{x_0+l}\frac{\lambda \delta(y') \delta(z') dx' dy' dz'}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}}\\
&=\frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\frac{x-x_0+\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+y^2+z^2}}{x-x_0-l+\sqrt{(x-x_0-l)^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)
\end{align}

Now,we can find the electric field by taking the gradient and then inserting the values $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ we get,

\begin{align}
E&=-\nabla{V}\\
&=-\frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{l}{x_0(l+x_0)}\hat{x}.
\end{align}